# Load Runner set-up error

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I downloaded HP Load-runner 12 Community Edition Additional Components. I tried to install but after extracting files to the temp folder then simply installation is closed. I didn't get the pop up to select the "LoadRunner full setup" please help for installing the LoadRunner in my system

Answer (score 3):

http://www8.hp.com/in/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/try-now.html

This is the proper place to download HP loadrunner latest version, Enter your correct details and after downloading take by default path of program files. I am sure it won't create any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in as Administrator to have the necessary rights for installation

Comment: Yup i signed in as administrator..
I think problem with the downloaded file..?
is there any other way to download and install it?

Comment: You would need to contact HP as they are the provider of the image